# grouping of subgrid along with grid when expanded and colasped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid where i have grouping for 1st and 2nd column such that if n rows have same value for the column then it will merge(using rowspan for first row and display:none for other rows with same value).

Also i have a subgrid there.now when i am expanding any row in the grid the other rows in the grouping are shifting to left.

here is my function for grouping:

```
attrSetting: function(rowId, val, rawObject, cm) {
   var attr = rawObject.attr[cm.name],result;
   if (attr.rowspan) {
       result = ' rowspan=' + '"' + attr.rowspan + '"';
   } else if (attr.display) {
       result = ' style="display:' + attr.display + '"';
   }
   return result;
}
```

i have write some code to handle this problem which increase rowspan by 1 each time i expand the subgrid and also decrease by 1 each time a subgrid is collapsed , which is below:

```
var rowspanValue = this.getElements("tbody>tr.ui-widget-content")[row_id - 1].getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_Stream]").rowSpan;
    this.getElements("tbody>tr.ui-widget-content")[row_id - 1].getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_Stream]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue + 1 });
    this.getElements("tbody>tr.ui-widget-content")[row_id - 1].getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_\\%CompletionAvg]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue + 1 });
    this.getElements("tbody>tr.ui-widget-content")[row_id - 1].getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_\\%WeightAvg]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue + 1 });
```

but this is not working as only the first row with the grouping has rowspan, so if i expand first row of each grouping then it works fine, for others the problem continues.

is there any way to detect all the rows with same grouping in DOM and setting the row span of the 1st row each time, or any other way to achieve it.

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set a custom attribute in formatter to the column i want grouping on and this is how i modified my code:

```
    cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject, cm) {
            return pathProjectModel.attrSetting(rowId, val, rawObject, cm) + 'attr-stream =' + val;
    } 



 subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
       var subgrid_table_id, rowspanValue;
       // grouping of subgrid along with grid
       var streamName = $('#idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'Stream');
       var streamGroup = widget.getElements('[attr-stream = "' + streamName + '"]');
        rowspanValue = streamGroup[0].rowSpan;
        for (var i = 0; i < streamGroup.length; i++) {
            streamGroup[i].setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue + 1 });
            streamGroup[i].getClosest("tr.ui-widget-content").getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_\\%CompletionAvg]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue + 1 });
            streamGroup[i].getClosest("tr.ui-widget-content").getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_\\%WeightAvg]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue + 1 });
        }
 }


subGridRowColapsed: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var rowspanValue;
    var streamName = $('#idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'Stream');
    var streamGroup = widget.getElements('[attr-stream = "' + streamName + '"]');
    rowspanValue = streamGroup[0].rowSpan;
    for (var i = 0; i < streamGroup.length; i++) {
         streamGroup[i].setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue - 1 });
         streamGroup[i].getClosest("tr.ui-widget-content").getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_\\%CompletionAvg]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue - 1 });
         streamGroup[i].getClosest("tr.ui-widget-content").getElement("[aria-describedby=idCommonGridTabledetailMainContainerPATHApp_\\%WeightAvg]").setAttributes({ rowspan: rowspanValue - 1 });
    }
}
```